# Going from `view-source:https://example.com` to `https://example.com` in Firefox

Tags: firefox, key-binding

In Firefox, when I want to view the source of a page, I often press `Ctrl-U`, which when I'm on `https://example.com` opens a new tab for `view-source:https://example.com`. Is there a way to do the opposite, going from `view-source:https://example.com` to `https://example.com` with a keyboard shortcut? (I don't like having to manually edit the URL every time).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in shortcut to achieve exactly what you wish. However, I can foresee two workarounds :

- You can use F12 to activate the Developer console and select the inspector. It will show you the code in the left-most pane. Please note that this is the **rendered** code, not the **source** code however. The code is collapsed by default, but you can use the selector by clicking on the below icon or Ctrl-Shift-C, click on the page element that you want to see, and the console will show you the expanded code.
  [image: Selector icon]
- You can use a Firefox add-on for this purpose. Using *View Source Switch*, the Ctrl+Alt+U will do what you need, in both direction (from web view to source view and reverse). https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/view-source-switch/